# Setting fake time in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, time, amazon-rds

We have some functionality in our apps where things only happen when time passes and we want to test those functions in integration/end-to-end tests. We have got fake time in Oracle by running the following query every 5 seconds:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system set fixed_date = ''' || TO_CHAR( SYSDATE + $fixed_date_days, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS' ) || ''' scope=memory';
```

This question has a way to do it on the connection level but it does not work in AWS RDS: [How to change CURRENT_TIMESTAMP temporarily to another time in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847542/how-to-change-current-timestamp-temporarily-to-another-time-in-mysql)

Ideally, we would like to get it done on a database level like Oracle but a connection-level solution can also work if there is something that works in AWS RDS too.

Comment: `set timestamp` works for me in rds; don't say "does not work"; always say what *does* happen.

Comment: So may be it's a permission issue for me? Do you know of another way to do it? Or a way to just set the timestamp at the database level?

Comment: if you can't do it for the connection, I think you'd have to change the time at the os level, and you definitely can't do that with rds.  yes, seems like a permission issue since it works for me.  but again, you aren't saying what happens when you try it, please do.